# How to correctly implement a delegating tokenizer in lucene 4.x?

Tags: java, lucene, delegates, tokenize

A naïve approach suggested by [documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html) under "Creating delegates" section doesn't work as expected, because it leads to the delegating Tokenizer contract violation:

```
private static class TokenizerWrapper extends Tokenizer {
  public TokenizerWrapper(Reader _input) {
    super(_input);
    delegate = new WhitespaceTokenizer(input);
  }

  @Override
  public void reset() throws IOException {
    logger.info("TokenizerWrapper.reset()");
    super.reset();
    delegate.setReader(input);
    delegate.reset();
  }

  @Override
  public final boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
    logger.info("TokenizerWrapper.incrementToken()");
    return delegate.incrementToken();
  }

  private final WhitespaceTokenizer delegate;
}
```

gives me the following log:

```
14:30:12.885 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.reset()
14:30:12.886 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.incrementToken()
14:30:12.889 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.incrementToken()
14:30:12.889 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.incrementToken()
14:30:12.897 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.reset()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation: close() call missing
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Tokenizer.setReader(Tokenizer.java:90)
    at test.GapTest$TestTokenizer.reset(GapTest.java:152)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenFilter.reset(TokenFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenFilter.reset(TokenFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:599)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:342)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:241)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:454)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1511)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1246)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1231)
    at test.GapTest.main(GapTest.java:67)
```

Overriding close() method like this:

```
  @Override
  public void close() throws IOException {
    logger.info("TokenizerWrapper.close()");
    super.close();
    logger.info("TokenizerWrapper.delegate.close()");
    tokenizer.close();
    // tokenizer.setReader(input);
  }
```

doesn't help either but with a different error:

```
15:36:49.561 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - setting field "text" to "some text"
15:36:49.569 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - Adding created document to the index
15:36:49.605 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - createComponents()
15:36:49.633 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper(_input)
15:36:49.638 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.reset()
15:36:49.639 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.incrementToken()
15:36:49.640 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.incrementToken()
15:36:49.640 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.incrementToken()
15:36:49.641 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.close()
15:36:49.641 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.delegate.close()
15:36:49.648 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - setting field "text" to "some text 1"
15:36:49.648 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - Adding created document to the index
15:36:49.648 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.reset()
15:36:49.648 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.incrementToken()
15:36:49.649 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.close()
15:36:49.649 [main] INFO  test.GapTest - TokenizerWrapper.delegate.close()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: first position increment must be > 0 (got 0) for field 'address'
    at    org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:617)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:342)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:241)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:454)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1511)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1246)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1231)
    at test.GapTest.main(GapTest.java:72)
```

that is,

1. it has successfully processed the first document (with "some text" in the "text" field),
2. then has started processing of the second document ("some text 1"),
3. [seemingly] succesfully processed the first token (the word "some", I've checked this in debugger),
4. and then has broken on the inconsistent internal state (`invertState.posIncrAttribute.getPositionIncrement(IndexableField field, boolean first)` in DefaultIndexingChain.PerField.invert() returned 0 while it's "normal" behaviour is to return 1)

Certainly I could handle this particular error by further wrapping and workarounding, but likely I've got a wrong direction in implementing such a seemingly easy task. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created an abstract class in my project which solves exactly this problem. The critical places are, of course, `incrementToken`, `reset`, `close` and `end` methods. Feel free just to use these bits or the whole thing.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.google.common.collect.Iterators;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Tokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.ClassicTokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.TypeAttribute;

import static vyre.util.search.LuceneVersion.VERSION_IN_USE;

/**
 * Allows to easily manipulate with {@link ClassicTokenizer} by delegating calls to it but hiding all implementation details.
 *
 * @author Mindaugas Žakšauskas
 */
public abstract class ClassicTokenizerDelegate extends Tokenizer {

    private final ClassicTokenizer classicTokenizer;

    private final CharTermAttribute termAtt;

    private final TypeAttribute typeAtt;

    /**
     * Internal buffer of tokens if any of standard tokens was split into many.
     */
    private Iterator<String> pendingTokens = Iterators.emptyIterator();

    protected ClassicTokenizerDelegate(Reader input) {
        super(input);
        this.classicTokenizer = new ClassicTokenizer(VERSION_IN_USE, input);
        termAtt = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        typeAtt = addAttribute(TypeAttribute.class);
    }

    /**
     * Is called during tokenization for each token produced by {@link ClassicTokenizer}. Subclasses can call {@link #setTerm(String)} to override
     * current token or {@link #setTerms(Iterator)} if current token needs to be split into more than one token.
     *
     * @return true whether next token exists false otherwise.
     * @see #getTerm()
     * @see #getType()
     * @see #setTerm(String)
     * @see #setTerms(Iterator)
     */
    protected abstract boolean onNextToken();

    /**
     * Subclasses can call this method during execution of {@link #onNextToken()} to retrieve current term.
     *
     * @return current term.
     * @see #getType()
     * @see #setTerm(String)
     * @see #setTerms(Iterator)
     * @see #onNextToken()
     */
    protected String getTerm() {
        return new String(termAtt.buffer(), 0, termAtt.length());
    }

    /**
     * Subclasses can call this method during execution of {@link #onNextToken()} to retrieve type of current term.
     *
     * @return type of current term.
     * @see #getTerm()
     * @see #setTerm(String)
     * @see #setTerms(Iterator)
     * @see #onNextToken()
     */
    protected String getType() {
        return typeAtt.type();
    }

    /**
     * Subclasses can call this method during execution of {@link #onNextToken()} to override current term.
     *
     * @param term the term to override with.
     * @see #getTerm()
     * @see #getType()
     * @see #setTerms(Iterator) setTerms(Iterator) - if you want to override current term with more than one term
     * @see #onNextToken()
     */
    protected void setTerm(String term) {
        termAtt.copyBuffer(term.toCharArray(), 0, term.length());
    }

    /**
     * Subclasses can call this method during execution of {@link #onNextToken()} to override current term with more than one term.
     *
     * @param terms the terms to override with.
     * @see #getTerm()
     * @see #getType()
     * @see #setTerm(String)
     * @see #onNextToken()
     */
    protected void setTerms(Iterator<String> terms) {
        setTerm(terms.next());
        pendingTokens = terms;
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        if (pendingTokens.hasNext()) {
            setTerm(pendingTokens.next());
            return true;
        }

        clearAttributes();
        if (!classicTokenizer.incrementToken()) {
            return false;
        }

        typeAtt.setType(classicTokenizer.getAttribute(TypeAttribute.class).type());        // copy type attribute from classic tokenizer attribute

        CharTermAttribute stTermAtt = classicTokenizer.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        setTerm(new String(stTermAtt.buffer(), 0, stTermAtt.length()));

        return onNextToken();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
        if (input != null) {
            input.close();
        }
        classicTokenizer.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void end() throws IOException {
        super.end();
        classicTokenizer.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() throws IOException {
        super.reset();
        this.classicTokenizer.setReader(input);        // important! input has to be carried over to delegate because of poor design of Lucene
        classicTokenizer.reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet! Likely it can be useful in my project, thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be useful to express it explicitly:

`TokenizerWrapper` and `delegate` don't share attribute set. So even the indexing of the first document seems correct, it's not, nothing goes to the indexer. In order to make a meaningful delegating one needs to mirror (completely or partially) attributes of the `delegate` in the `TokenizerWrapper`, like @mindas does in `setTerm()`.

Or maybe I'm wrong, and there're some "magical machinery" which would allow to reuse `delegate.attributes` as `TokenizerWrapper.attributes`?